# Want to run a query which gives me results between two dates. I have timestamp in unix epoch format

Tags: mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I have got timestamps in epoch UNIX format. I want to run a query by directly giving date and not timestamp. How is that possible?

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)
FROM report_data
WHERE timestamp = '1399376713'
```

I used this to convert to human readable format.

My database is something like this

timestamp   event_type  flags
1399357862  701         null

I want to give a particular date in  my query and get the result.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show attempts you have made so we can further assist.

Comment: Edit your code into your main post.

Comment: You need to edit this question. Where have you 'got timestamps in epoch UNIX format'? Add code samples to show what you're trying to achieve - it's not really clear exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function.

This assumes that your table contains columns in `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, and you are wanting to supply 32-bit integer values in the query.

For example:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.datetime_col >= FROM_UNIXTIME( ? )
   AND t.datetime_col <  FROM_UNIXTIME( ? )
```

The integer values supplied as arguments to the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function will be interpreted as unix-style "seconds since epoch" integer values, and be converted to a DATETIME value using the current timezone setting of the client connection.

This approach will enable MySQL to use a range scan operation using an index with a leading column of `datetime_col`.

---

What's not at all clear is what the **datatype** of your column is, and what values you want to supply in the query.  If the columns is datatype `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` (which would be the normative pattern for storing date/time data), then you can specify date literals in standard MySQL format, `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`.

```
 WHERE t.timestamp_col >= '2015-02-11 07:00' 
   AND t.timestamp_col <  '2015-02-11 23:30:00'
```

If you are storing the "timestamp" as an integer value, then you will need the right side of the predicates to return an integer value, e.g.

```
 WHERE t.integer_col  >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-10')
   AND t.integer_col  <  UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2015-02-10' + INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
```

Comment: My datatype is timestamp.